# Combining lists of nested dictionaries in Ansible without looping

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I would like to combine the following nested and "unnested" item dictionaries into a single list of dictionaries.

Input data:

```yaml
vars:
  nested:
    - nest1: 
      - name: item1
        info: foo
    - nest2: 
      - name: item2
        info: bar
  unnested:
    - name: item3
      info: baz
    - name: item4
      info: foobar
```

Desired outcome:

```yaml
all_items: [ 
  {name: item1, info: foo}, 
  {name: item2, info: bar}, 
  {name: item3, info: baz}, 
  {name: item4, info: foobar}
]
```

Pseudocode attempt:

```
all_items = [ unnested + nested.*.* ]
```

I know I can do this with a loop for the nested items and then just append them to the unnested list, but I would prefer to use `combine()`, `json_query`, or other Ansible filter to create the new variable in a single line as opposed to a loop task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that without JMESPath (`json_query`), with the filters [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map), [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/dict2items_filter.html) and [`flatten`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/flatten_filter.html).
But I have to confess that I like the brevity of JMESPath in those use cases:

- the [flatten operator `[]`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#flatten-operator) is the equivalent of the `flatten` filter
- a [multi-select hash `*`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#multiselect-hash) can easily replace the need to `map` the filter `dict2items` and then `map` the selection of the resulting `value` attribute

So, given the task

```yaml
- set_fact:
    all_items: "{{ nested | json_query('[].*[][]') + unnested }}"
```

You get your expected output.

As compared to a lengthy:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    all_items: >-
      {{ 
        nested | map('dict2items') | flatten 
          | map(attribute='value') | flatten 
          + unnested 
      }}
```

Which also does the job.

---

For demonstration purpose, the two tasks wrapped in a `block` to assign variable to both:

```yaml
- block:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ nested | json_query('[].*[][]') + unnested }}"

  - debug:
      msg: >-
        {{
          nested | map('dict2items') | flatten 
            | map(attribute='value') | flatten
            + unnested
        }}

  vars:
    nested:
      - nest1:
        - name: item1
          info: foo
      - nest2:
        - name: item2
          info: bar
    unnested:
      - name: item3
        info: baz
      - name: item4
        info: foobar
```

Yields:

```
TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - info: foo
    name: item1
  - info: bar
    name: item2
  - info: baz
    name: item3
  - info: foobar
    name: item4

TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - info: foo
    name: item1
  - info: bar
    name: item2
  - info: baz
    name: item3
  - info: foobar
    name: item4
```